# Load image and set it when it's finish loading

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have an `AsyncTask` that gets a URL as a parameter, and returns a `Bitmap` of an image from that URL when it finishes. When I start the activity, I want to show a text (instead of the image) saying "loading...", run the `ImageFetcher` in the background, and when it finishes, set the image to the `ImageView`.

The problem is, if I run:

```
ivPoster.setImageBitmap(imgFetcher.execute(m.getPosterUrl()).get());
```

It doesn't load the entire activity until the image is loaded. It skips frames.

So I set an on finish listener on the task, that returns the bitmap, and tried to set the image after the bitmap is retrieved:

```
imgFetcher.setOnFinishListener(new OnTaskFinished() {

    @Override
    public void onFinish(Bitmap bm) {
        // hide the loading image text
        tvLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // place the image
        ivPoster.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
});

imgFetcher.execute(m.getPosterUrl());
```

Yet it still skips frames and 'does too much work on the main thread'.
How can I prevent the frame skipping?

Comment: Please look at the second code. There it doesn't call `get()` but rather `onFinish` with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead utilize the UI thread in AsyncTask. If you run the code in that thread to load the image, the rest of the program will not have to wait.

Use this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more insight. You can use either the `onPostExecute()` method or `onProgressUpdate()` method instead of causing wait in the background thread.

The main thread is the same as the UI thread. You should be using that to make changes in your UI. That is so that your application does not wait for graphics to load before executing background code, instead doing them simultaneously. In order to use the ImageView from AsyncTask, you can make the ImageView global if the AsyncTask is a subclass and instantiate before execution. Otherwise, pass it as a parameter to the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I actually thought of that, but I read somewhere that changes to the UI should be done only from the main thread. Isn't that problematic?

Comment: @Gofilord onPostExecute method runs on the UI thread.The purpose of onPostExecute is to publish results (such as updating the view hierarchy, or setting text in a text view) that must be done on the UI thread.

Comment: The main thread IS the UI thread. Sorry for confusion, but you should be using that to make changes in your UI. That is so that your application does not wait for graphics to load before executing background code, instead doing them simultaneously.

Comment: So if I do want to set the bitmap from `onPostExecute()`, how do I address the `ImageView` from there?

Comment: You can either pass the ImageView as a parameter to the constructor of AsyncTask or make a separate method and pass along the downloaded bitmap. You can then set the bitmap 
`ivPoster.setImageBitmap(bm)`;

Comment: Make the ImageView global if the AsyncTask is a subclass and instantiate before execution. Otherwise, pass it as a parameter to the AsyncTask.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot. I think it will be helpful for other people if you update your answer with the info you added in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
private class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView mImageView;
    String mUrl;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageview, String url) {
        this.mImageView = imageview;
        this.mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Download here

    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associate it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Hope the code snippet helps

Answer (score 0):

You can think about Picasso lib: http://square.github.io/picasso/

or

Universal Image Loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks, but I rather not use external libraries for this one.